# How to create a check box that shows its state depending on a changing variable?

Tags: android, variables, checkbox

I have a list with items that when clicked open a new activity (recipe activity from now on) which shows an image, 2 text views and a check box.

the list is populated by an xml file with string-arrays.
depending on what was clicked the recipe activity shows info which is drawn from another xml file. Something like this:

1.(in list)

(String product = ((TextView) view).getText().toString();)

2.(in recipe activity)

if(product.equals("Naan"))
                    sastojci = getString(R.string.sNaan);

Anyway, the problem is following:

i want a check box which can read the product variable, check if it was selected before and put in favorites (shared preferences) then depending on if is in favorites or not to show its correct state (checked or unchecked).

because right now i have a check box that is the same for any item on the list i select...if i select the first item it will stay checked on all items,same for unchecked...

how can something like this be done?

Comment: Try saving the state of each `CheckBox` using shared preferences..

Comment: there is only one checkbox, and i saved its state in shared prefs. i need that one checkbox to show checked or unchecked based on what was clicked...

Comment: You were right, your question is a bit confusing. Can you attach some screenshots?

Comment: will do as soon as i can! 
just to clarify, i have one activity which has those textviews,image and a checkbox, but somehow i need that one checkbox to show different states depending on what says in the textview...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, i think i got it...

First save the state of `CheckBox` for selected string:

```
SharedPreferences mySettings = getSharedPreferences("mySettingsfile", MODE_PRIVATE);

mySettingsfile.Editor prefEditor = mySettings .edit(); 
prefEditor.putBoolean("selectedstring", myCheckbox.isChecked());
prefEditor.commit();
```

Now, load the settings by

```
SharedPreferences mySettings = getSharedPreferences("mySettingsfile", MODE_PRIVATE);
myCheckbox.setChecked(mySettings .getBoolean("selectedstring", false));
```

Here, the check state for each string is stored separately.

Comment: ok this is much more simpler than i thought, i will try it out then let u know, tnx man! :D